# How to check if a given number is a perfect number recursively in C

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I have this HW about writing a recursive function in C that returns 0 or 1 based on if a given number is a perfect number or not.
<sup><sub>A perfect number is a number that is equal to the sum of its divisors. For example, 6 is equal to (1 + 2 + 3), so it is a perfect number.</sub></sup>

I've managed to write a recursive function that calculates the Sum of a given number's divisors, but the output is the sum of the divisors, not 0 or 1. I have zero idea how to write a recursive function that returns 0 or 1 and at the same time calculate the sum of divisors and do the comparison.

This is my code that outputs the sum of divisors :

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int check(int n, int b) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (b == 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    else if (n % b == 0) {
        return b + check(n, b - 1);
    } else {
        return check(n, b - 1);
    }
}

void main() {
    int n, res, b;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        b = n / 2;
    } else {
        b = n / 2 + 1;
    }
    res = check(n, b);
    printf("%d est un nombre %d", n, res);
}
```

Comment: Split this into two functions. One calculates the sum of divisors recursively. The other compares this result with the original number.

Comment: I have considered that approach but I was wondering if there is a way to cheat things and do everything in one function, I can't tell if that would be considered a perfectly correct answer I tend to overthink questions a lot cause of the way teachers grade things, but to quote the question it said "write a recursive C function that returns 1 if an int passed in parameters is a perfect number and 0 if not", like it's so vague about what's allowed and what's not, Do you think I should just go for it and split that shit and stop overthinking it?

Comment: What are `b` and `n`?

Comment: so n is the original number that you read to check if it's a perfect number or not and b is the potential divisor, so essentially the value that we are gonna check if it's a divisor of n or not, side note : b is initiated in main() as half of n cause no number can be divided by a number that's bigger than it's half

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that 1 is not a perfect number. The sum of all divisors when deciding if a number is perfect excludes the number itself. 0 is also not perfect, since perfect numbers have to be positive.

```
if (n < 2) return 0;
```

Assume the accumulated sum of divisors is passed into the function. Then, when you reach the stopping point, you return whether the sum is equal the number. To make this logic simple, the stopping point can be when your candidate divisor reaches 0.

```
if (b == 0) return sum == n;
```

Your recursive call will now check to see if your candidate divisor should be added to the sum.

```
assert(b > 0);
if ((n % b) == 0) sum += b;
return check(n, b-1, sum);
```

Implemented this way, the function becomes tail recursive. This would allow your recursive function to be optimized into a simple loop by a compiler that supports this optimization.

The initial call to your function would pass 0 in for the initial sum.

```
answer = check(n, n/2, 0);
```

In my own code, I would be tempted to define a helper function that only takes the single argument.

```
int check_if_perfect(int n) { return check(n, n/2, 0); }
```

This way, the caller wouldn't need to worry about the other arguments.

```
answer = check_if_perfect(n);
```

Comment: imma try this approach it seems like it would work perfectly

Comment: https://tio.run/##TY/NboMwEITvPMWUisoI0sb0R6iE9EV6wcYJVsNS2dAeqjw7tXFKupe1dsff7MjNUcr5VpM8Ta3Czo6tHu67fXQdNdYqM/rZrGmE7JT8YP5FOXwTodmpT/ETRXClD2CEHYoURo2TIWyrsAkwJrAHT6sg9qhWoAbhAaJaCV7kFivDOaB2qupqsvUDZ5VApN4dl/LSzG0c46YOkDcIZIvRqxMHl3MgXfghmUslMp4vearoHM1fg27RN5rYn0MIb5QNlO9OnxSYlQ0dWJy0cX5HqT@M/z/JyevVocjX@L4@jUMuf6HsiIlAQy@MQtK@U5wvXuvJ7qQNxxYcBR7xhGe8oChR8qL8BQ

Comment: Using some math facts about divisors, you can reduce the runtime complexity to O(sqrt(n)) instead of the current O(n). (See link above.)